# Morphism from Projective Set to Affine Set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

in Mumford's Red Book, it is claimed that if $P$ is a homogeneous prime ideal, and $X:=V(P)$, then $X \cap {P_n(k)}_{X_0}$ is an affine variety. But in understanding the proof which I have attached, I am confused as to how he defines a morphism $\phi$ from projective space affine space. How is one to understand such a morphism? Thanks!
[image: Mumford proof]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach the image. Please see the update.

Comment: Points in $X \cap \mathbf{P}_n(k)_{X_0}$ are of the form $[x_0:x_1:\cdots:x_n]$ where $x_0 \ne 0$. The map $\varphi$ is then defined by $[x_0:x_1:\cdots:x_n] \mapsto \left(\frac{x_1}{x_0},\ldots,\frac{x_n}{x_0}\right)$, which is well-defined because $x_0 \ne 0$, and since scaling the projective coordinates doesn't affect the ratios $\frac{x_i}{x_0}$.

Comment: I understand that, but why is $\phi$ a "morphism?" Mumford defines a morphism between irreducible affine sets to be a map defined by polynomials. How is this $\phi$ such?

Comment: Ah. The issue then is that $X \cap \mathbf{P}_n(k)_{x_0}$ is not an irreducible affine set, and then you need to define morphisms differently. See Definition 5 which should be on the next page.

Comment: Right, but it's also not a prevariety which is what Def 5 deals with.

Comment: @kfriend Morphisms can always be defined locally. Also, you can define a morphism between affine sets (not necessarily irreducible) to also be a map defined by polynomials. Now say you have a space $X$ covered with two affine sets $X = U\cup V$, then for any space $Y$, you can define a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ to be a morphism $U\rightarrow Y$ and a morphism $V\rightarrow Y$ which agree on the intersection $U\cap V$.

Note that the intersection of affine sets is affine (if you're dealing with varieties), so this is all good.

Comment: @kfriend $X$ is definitely a prevariety; the reason is that the map $\varphi$ he gives ends up being an isomorphism (of ringed spaces!) of $X \cap \mathbf{P}_n(k)_{x_0}$ with a closed subset of $k^n$. This notion of isomorphism I don't see spelled out explicitly in Mumford (in fact, it's ambiguous what he means by an affine variety when he says it's a ringed space which is *isomorphic* to a closed subset of a $k^n$—what does that mean?) but you can define such an isomorphism as a homeomorphism which induces an isomorphism of structure sheaves.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!